# Why my qtconsole display nothing but blank?

Tags: macos, python-3.5, jupyter, qtconsole

Why is my qtconsole displaying nothing but blank?

platform: macOS Sierra,
python version: Python3.5.1

[image]

[image]

Comment: I met the same problem on Windows. I ran `%qtconsole`, then it appeared but absolutely blank.

Answer (score -1):

Hit cmd+T to start new kernel (in new tab). This works for me on macOS Sierra.